# JSONArrayRequest Not Working

Tags: android

I am trying to get `deliverycount` from the server using `JSONArrayRequest` but I am not getting any response.`PHP` is fine and working but the code in android not getting the `request`.
Can someone please help me with this problem? I am not getting any errors in `logcat` also.

```
public class PendingDeliveryList extends Fragment {
    TextView delivery_List_Count;
    TextView delivered_List_Count;
    String companyName,userName;
    SwipeRefreshLayout mSwipeRefreshLayout;
    public PendingDeliveryList() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pending_delivery_list, container, false);
    delivery_List_Count=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.deliveryListCount);
    delivered_List_Count=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.deliveredListCount);
    mSwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.delivery_list_count_swipe);
    return v;}
@Override
public void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    userName=this.getArguments().getString("userId");
    companyName=this.getArguments().getString("companyName");
    String server_URL= PathUrls.pathUrl+"evs_getemployeedeliverycounts.php?db="+userName+"&userid="+companyName;
    //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "userName"+userName+"companyName"+companyName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    //Create a volley request Object
    //sample[{}]
    JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest=new JsonArrayRequest(server_URL, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "test1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.d("pending Delivery Count",response.toString());
            if (response!=null)
            {
                try{
                    delivery_List_Count.setText(response.getJSONObject(0).getString("deliverlist"));
                    delivered_List_Count.setText(response.getJSONObject(0).getString("deliveredlist"));

                }catch (JSONException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    });
    VolleySingleton.getsInstance().getRequestQueue().add(jsonArrayRequest);
    Log.d("delivery Count",server_URL);
}
}
```

Comment: show your json.

Comment: post your response here

Comment: `[{"deliverlist":"17","deliveredlist":"1"}]` this is my json response

Comment: add log in onErrorResponse method so that we get the exact error

Comment: there is no error in `logcat`

Comment: I hope u added as below:                                                                      new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
Log.d("error",""+error.toString);
        }

Comment: @SachinGawai Ok I got this error: D/error: com.android.volley.ParseError: org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray

Comment: You json String contains a <br /> tag so it can't be parsed.

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya So what is a possible solution for this.

Comment: in onResponse just print the response and comment below code and see the response

Comment: @SaiSi Read above comment .

Comment: @SachinGawai onResponse I am getting this: https://xx.xxx.xxx.xx/FolderName/evs_getemployeedeliverycounts.php?db=sai&userid=saisi

Comment: i think you have problem with your rest api,did u hit it on postman to check its response?

Comment: @SachinGawai sorry I don't get that postman?. I did the same thing for registration and its working fine

Comment: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en and install it and test your API there first

Comment: @SachinGawai I added it to Chrome and tested it seems to like my URL is returning result fine.

Comment: @SachinGawai I just tested URL

Comment: if its working fine then it has to be, in response as well right, which is not coming in onResponse method?

Comment: @SachinGawai Can you make this discussion to move to chat I don't have enough reputation to move it to chat. I need clear this problem immediately

Answer (score 0):

After hours of research and deep looking into my own code, I found this simple blind error. And I am really sorry for wasting others time.

```
String server_URL= PathUrls.pathUrl+"evs_getemployeedeliverycounts.php?db="+companyName+"&userid="+userNAme;
```